# DISTINCT in a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, distinct

When executing SQL queries  I have been trying to figure out the following:
In this example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AL.id, AL.name
FROM albums AL
```

why is there a need to specify distinct? I thought that the `Id` being a primary key was enough to avoid duplicate results.

Comment: If the `ID` is a primary key, then the `DISTINCT` is pointless.

Comment: 1. I didn't downvote your question.  2.  If a column is naturally unique in the `SELECT` set, providing `DISTINCT` isn't going to change the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `distinct` you are specifying that you want the **whole row** to be distinct.  For example if you have two rows:

1. ID=1 and Name='Joe Smith'
2. ID=2 and Name='Joe Smith'

then your query is going to return **both rows** because the different ID values make the rows distinct.

However, if you are selecting **only** the ID column (and it's your primary key) then the distinct is pointless.

If you're trying to find all of the unique names then you'd want to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AL.name
FROM albums AL
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, in your case there should be no need for the word distinct because you are asking for the id and the name. Now, for sake of example where distinct is necessary, say you had multiple id's with the same name. Let It Be is an album by both the Beatles and the Replacements. And let's say you were using your database to write out labels that only included the names of the albums. The query you would want would be:

```
    select distinct al.name
    from albums al;
```

Sometimes your database is not perfect and it ends up with a bunch of junk data. If the id has not been designated as unique, you might end up with duplicate records, and then you might want to avoid seeing the duplicates in your query results.